# Check constraint on Postgres to insert only capital alphabetic letters only

Tags: regex, postgresql, check-constraints

I have a text field on my PostgreSQL database that I want to store only capital alphabetic letters not but not special characters in a column.

I have already used `CHECK (location_id ~* '[A-Z]')` I am able to insert both alphabetic and special characters that doesn't not solve my requirement.

Comment: Try `CHECK (location_id ~* '^[A-Z]+$')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew W/o the asterisk, `CHECK (location_id ~ '^[A-Z]*$')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE)  the `~*` operator checks regex "case insensitively". If you want to only allow uppercase letters, you need to use the `~` operator which checks case sensitively.

`'[A-Z]'` only allows a single character. If you want multiple characters, you need `'[A-Z]*'` or `'[A-Z]+'` if you want *at least* one character.

This only matches the uppercase characters *somewhere* in the string. To ensure that **all** characters are uppercase you need to anchor the regex to the start and end of the string using `^` and `$`

```
CHECK (location_id ~ '^[A-Z]+$')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
CHECK (location_id ~ '^[A-Z]+$')
```

or

```
CHECK (location_id ~ '^[[:upper:]]+$')
```

The issues are two:

- `~*` matches in a case insensitive way, so `[A-Z]` matches lowercase letters, too
- `[A-Z]` matches one uppercase ASCII letter anywhere in the string, so other chars are also allowed. `^[A-Z]+$` matches a string consisting of only uppercase letters.

Note that `[[:upper:]]` can also be used to match uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Wiktor Stribiżew  the above 2 I have tired yes I cannot insert the special char but small alphabets were able to insert in both.